# mern app gives 500 (internal server error) while registering user

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to register user in my web app but I get an error in console "POST http://localhost:3001/auth/register 500 (Internal Server Error)".

This is the fetch request in the frontend.

```
    const register = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        for (let value in values) {
            formData.append(value, values[value]);
        }

        const savedUserResponse = await fetch(
            "http://localhost:3001/auth/register",
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData,
            }
        );
        const savedUser = await savedUserResponse.json();
        onSubmitProps.resetForm();

        if (savedUser) {
            setPageType("login");
        }
    };
```

this is from main 'index.js' file

```
app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
```

'authRoutes' has been imported
from ./routes/auth.js

```
import express from "express";
import { register, login } from "../controllers/auth.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register", register);

router.post("/login", login);

export default router;
```

and this is my controller ./controllers/auth.js

```
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import User from "../models/User.js";

/* REGISTER */
export const register = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { firstName, lastName, email, password, role, hostel } = req.body;

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
        const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        const newUser = new User({
            firstName,
            lastName,
            email,
            password: passwordHash,
            role,
            hostel,
        });

        const savedUser = await newUser.save();
        res.status(201).json(savedUser);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
};

/* LOGGING IN */
export const login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body();
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
        if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "User does not exist" });

        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!isMatch)
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: " Invalid credentials " });

        const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        delete user.password;
        res.status(200).json({ token, user });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
};
```

i am still learning. So any help would be appreciated. thank you

i tried console.log(firstName) in the controller in register . the logged 'undefined' then it throws error 500 (Internal server error) in the console. And, in network tab of my browser inspect, in 'payload' section it shows the data that i want to send BUT in 'preview'"error:"data and salt arguments required"" . i am not sure what to do.

Comment: You can try genSaltSync instead of genSalt as you are performing an async operation.

Comment: but i have used await before genSalt. I tried with genSaltSync too but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've installed bcrypt and body-parser as dependencies in your project and import body-parser in your main 'index.js' file  like this :

```
 import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

If it is already imported then go to the ./controllers/auth.js file and update the code :

```
export const register = async (req, res) => {
 
 console.log(req.body,"request"); 
 
    try {
        const { firstName, lastName, email, password, role, hostel } = req.body;

        // Check all the fields are not empty
        if (!password ) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Password is required" });
        }
        if (!firstName) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "First name is required" });
        }

        if (!lastName) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Last name is required" });
        }

        if (!email) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Email is required" });
        }

        if (!role) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Role is required" });
        }

        if (!hostel) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Hostel is required" });
        }

        const saltRounds = 10; // Number of salt rounds for bcrypt

        const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);

        const newUser = new User({
            firstName,
            lastName,
            email,
            password: passwordHash,
            role,
            hostel,
        });

        const savedUser = await newUser.save();
        res.status(201).json(savedUser);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
};
```

If data is not appearing in req.body or fields are missing, check your frontend code to ensure that the FormData you're sending contains all the fields required for user registration.